# Kubernetes environment variables read in static react project

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

Is is possible to read environment variables, defined in containers, in a react-app which is created using create-react-app?
eg
Deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
..
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          env:
            - name: REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE
              value: abc
```

Dockerfile:

```
..
CMD PORT=8080 npm start
```

Package.json:

```
"start":"react-scripts start"
"build":"react-scripts build"
```

In App.js:
`process.env.REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE` returns undefined

Comment: It should work like you described.
Can you try `console.log(process.env)` and see what's written in the pod logs?

Comment: Or for debugging, start by skipping npm and use `CMD PORT=8080 env`

Comment: Thanks @GeertPt you are right it did work! Not sure why i was seeing undefined.
Couple of questions:

1. with npm start, is it building + serving in the development server? At what stage do the environment variables get injected?

2. Is it better practice to define the vars in ConfigMap and read from there? How to do that?

Comment: 1. no idea, I just answered because I know Kubernetes, not npm or reactjs.
2. configmaps can be mounted as property files on your pod. It might be cleaner if you have a lot of them, but not necessarilty better...

Comment: Hi @GeertPt apologies, but i had made a mistake saying it worked.  process.env returns undefined after all.  I guess process.env is injected by development server.
Either i need to :
1. specify environment variable during build time npm run build
2. inject env variable during run time
Any idea how to do either of these?

Comment: @HuzanToorkey: From what I found, in react, env variables are defined during build time. So if you build your react web first before running your yml to define those env variables, process.env.REACT_APP_variable will return undefined.

Have you found a solution to address it yet ?

Answer (score -1):

You can export those variables in your Dockerfile by doing:

```bash
ARG REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE

ENV REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE=${REACT_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE}

..

CMD PORT=8080 npm start
```

Comment: This only works with build args, so during build time. 
OP wants the set the value at runtime via kubernetes.